# How to configure Hive EMR to use S3 as the default filesystem and warehouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I'm trying to configure EMR Hive to use S3 as the database warehouse and default location for internal/managed databases/tables.

I have already configured S3 as the default filesystem for hadoop, by setting the `fs.defaultFS` to `s3://..` in core-site.xml of the namenode host -

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>s3://***********</value>
</property>
```

Some properties were present by default which I didn't touch

```
   <property>
      <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
      <value>com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.s3n.impl</name>
      <value>com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.s3.buffer.dir</name>
      <value>/mnt/s3,/mnt1/s3</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>

   <property>
     <name>fs.s3.buckets.create.region</name>
     <value>sa-east-1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>fs.s3bfs.impl</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem</value>
   </property>

   <property>
     <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.s3.impl</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.EMRFSDelegate</value>
   </property>
```

This works as expected with the `hadoop fs` commands and I'm able to access the S3 bucket.

To configure hive to use S3 I made these changes to the hive-site.xml of the namenode host where `hive-server2` also is running

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>s3://***********</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> .
  <value>s3://***********/user/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
```

After restarting the components `hadoop-hdfs-namenode`, `hive-server2`, `hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager`, I try to use the Hive CLI to create a database.

`create database test`

But when I describe that database, it gives me its location as `hdfs://..`

I got that fixed using `s3:a//` as the URI scheme in hive-site.xml.. the database location is then `s3a://`.. but then when I try to insert data into it.. but it fails with the error -

```
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

hadoop classpath has the path where hadoop-aws jars are present -

/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*::/etc/tez/conf:/usr/lib/tez/*:/usr/lib/tez/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-hadoop-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/kinesis/lib/emr-kinesis-hadoop.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/cloudwatch-sink/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*

Please mention in the comment if any other information is required to debug the issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hive-site doesn't use fs.defaultFS... In the hive-env file, you need to setup `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` to point at the directory containing hdfs and core xml files. Also, not sure what `s3bfs` is